# my sql best practice with php for counting rows

Tags: php, mysql, count

1) Count record:

```
//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysql_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
    die('Could not connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
    die("cannot use the database");
}
mysql_set_charset('charset=utf8',$link); 

$query="SELECT `id`FROM `table` WHERE `abc`='123'";
$result=mysql_query($query);               
$count= mysql_num_rows($result);
```

I am using this to count the record. The table has 500K records. What is the best practice to count the records?

2) I am beginner @  mysql and php. Did I miss something in the above script? I think I need to close mysql connection in the end !

Comment: You missed using PDO / mysqli :)

Comment: I have recently learned that mysql should not be used any more. Use as Jack said - PDO and mysqli.

Comment: Question itself is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796080/more-efficient-way-to-count-mysql-rows-via-php?rq=1  - and others. Otherwise, you'll only get comments on mysqli / PDO (as Jack said, you should be using those functions and not the soon-to-be-dropped mysql ones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql has a count function:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

so you could use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE abc=123
```

or whatever condition.

Answer (score 3):

When you only need the count the record, you should use `COUNT()` function of mysql, instead of load all of the records.

```
$query="SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM `table` WHERE `abc`='123'";
```

Second, use `PDO` instead of `mysql_` functions.

Comment: He did not mention mysqli - but mysql_ the deprecated library

Comment: Yes, but to choose one, `PDO` is better choice, imaging one day you need to change database.

Comment: @xdazz Both have their merits. `mysqli_` is useful if someone is quite comfortable with the `mysql_` functions, as the changes are minute.

Answer (score 2):

Why not the let the DB do it - What about a simple

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE abc=123;
```

Comment: @xdazz Their answer is better and has more pointers to good code

Answer (score 1):

```
$query="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `table` WHERE `abc`='123'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

This will work fast and light. Also, as `Jack` said in the comments above, you should use either MySQLi, or PDO, because the MySQL addon has been deprecated by PHP.

Comment: -1.  That mysql_num_rows will cause all 500k rows to be transfered to PHP-land.  (Though, with buffered results, they may be anyway... but no reason to force it.)

Comment: @Corbin: Understandable. But that first block of code is the OP's, not mine. I very rarely condone the use of calling unnecessary data into play.

Comment: @Spiritfyre well you did in your answer ;-)

Comment: @Spiritfyre Hrmm, seems I may have misunderstood your answer?  I interpreted it as saying that `the following code is accurate, lighter on the server and easier to read` where "the following code" meant the first snippet.  That could be clarified a bit, in my opinion.  Also, using mysql_num_rows for the sole purpose of counting rows is never correct for a table of 500k rows.  That would be horrendously slow.

Comment: @AdrianCornish... Whoops. I see it now. Editing to remove that embarrassing blemish. :P

Comment: @Corbin: I see what you mean. When I wrote `//is replaced with`, I thought that made it fairly clear, but I can see what you mean. I'll edit it to make it more clear.